# Hostile answers during US Supreme Court Senate confirmation hearings

Tags: united-states, senate, supreme-court

My question is: Does it help or hinder to answer questions with hostility during United States Supreme Court Senate confirmation hearings?

There are many examples in real life where a senate asks inane or insulting questions of a candidate, all of them so controversial that it would be hard to not express my opinion so I will give a fictitious example so that the focus is the actual question.

Fiction:

*Back in the day there was a Supreme Court decision that stated that checkered pants worn with striped shirts was a protected right according to the US constitution.  Since then every time a Supreme Court nominee is brought before the Senate, their support of striped shirts is questioned vehemently.  Today the nominee is asked: I don't think I have seen you or any of your family ever wear striped shirts, and I have proof here that you wrote that checkered pants do not go with your complexion since you are [a winter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_analysis_(art)#Seasonal_skin_tone_color_matching_for_clothing_and_cosmetics). This puts us in the difficult position that you will be a no vote on this case. Is that how you would vote?*

The classy answer is: *I will respect Supreme Court precedent and will rule impartially in all my cases.*

The answer I would give is: *Pictures? Who takes pictures of their entire life? This is just a question to win political points and has nothing to do with my judicial credentials.  I'm not answering this highly unlikely scenario.*

Does anyone know of real life examples where a hostile answer was given and confirmation was rescinded because of this?

Comment: Define "nothing bad happened".  That nobody thought "I don't much care for that" doesn't sound like a reasonable expectation.  Whereas "he wasn't shot in the face right there" would be too easy to satisfy.

Comment: @zibadawa I edited to what I mean by bad, the confirmation was not given

Comment: @agc not a typo, probably a bad joke referring to the fashion style of spring, summer, fall, winter such as someone who looks good in whites, greys and blacks is a winter. Orange browns and yellows is a fall.

Answer (score 3):

I went through the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsuccessful_nominations_to_the_Supreme_Court_of_the_United_States) list of the unsuccessful Supreme Court nominees. I could find no instances where being rude or snappy in confirmation hearings resulted in a withdrawn or rejected nomination. Typically Supreme Court nominees are very circumspect in their replies, especially if they know their nomination is likely to be controversial.

Comment: Yeah--it's possible it has happened, especially if we open it up to the wider world of judicial and executive appointees, but I was unable to find specific examples.

Comment: If I recall, Justice Goursch was quite snippy at times with his answers.  Justice Kagan famously quipped that she was doing what all good Jews do on Christmas Day:  Eating Chinese Food, when asked about her whereabouts on a particular Christmas (I have no idea why, I just remembered the response.).